# Switching Many Switches with one Input

Tags: multiplexer, switch

I have a situation where I need to select between two signals, lets say 1A or 2B and route it to output 3C. I need to do this six times (2A or 2B to output 2C, 3A or 3B to output 3C, etc.).

These all need to switch based on one output from my chip.

What sort of component do I need for this? I think it's something like a 2:1 spdt multiplexer, but something doesn't seem quite right.

I've been looking at a bunch of data sheets and I cannot seem to find a chip which switches many 2:1 switches based on ONE input. Does such a thing exists? Or am I just way of the mark here? Not sure.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: One output from the Arduino can go to many SELECT pins of multiplexers or switches. So where's your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Almost, you will need two [74157](https://www.calstatela.edu/sites/default/files/groups/Department%20of%20Electrical%20and%20Computer%20Engineering/labs/74157.pdf) (or similar chips) to switch 8 pairs of TTL level logic signals down to 8 individual signal.

[image]